# PHPUnit: How to Mock Multiple Calls to the Same Method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I was looking to get different return values for the same method while calling it multiple times. I tried many things but did not get an exact answer for this.

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Test')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->setMethods(array('testMethod'))
                ->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('testMethod')->will($this->returnValue(true));
$mock->expects($this->second())->method('testMethod')->will($this->returnValue(false));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls` method

```
$mock
    ->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('testMethod')
    ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(true, false);
```

Alternative (for phpunit < 4):

```
$mock
    ->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('testMethod')
    ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(true, false));
```

Comment: Checking the source code, it looks like `willReturn()` can also handle multiple arguments to allow for consecutive calls.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://www.aventinesolutions.nl/mediawiki2/index.php/PHPUnit:_How_to_Mock_Multiple_Calls_to_the_Same_Method) link which helps me to get it done using `at($index)` method. It returns a matcher that matches when the method it is evaluated for is invoked at the given `$index`.

The `$index` parameter for the `at()` matcher refers to the index, starting at zero, in all method invocations for a given mock object. Exercise caution when using this matcher as it can lead to brittle tests which are too closely tied to specific implementation details. [More Details](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Test')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->setMethods(array('testMethod'))
                ->getMock();
$mock->expects($this->at(0))->method('testMethod')->will($this->returnValue(true));
$mock->expects($this->at(1))->method('testMethod')->will($this->returnValue(false));
```

Comment: Great trick if you receive the expectations in an array. You can loop the array and iterate on adding each expectation.

Comment: @XaviMontero I used `at` here because the method was being multiple time in a loop so I want to return a different result on the index when the function was called.

Comment: n.b. `at()` is deprecated in PHPUnit 9 and will be removed in version 10